# Proof of consistency of propositional logic

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, solution-verification, incompleteness

Here's how they proved it in the source I was reading:

Assume both sentences $S$ and $\lnot S$ are derivable from the axioms (where $\lnot S$ is the negation of $S$).

We notice that $p\rightarrow (\lnot p \rightarrow q)$ is a theorem of the system.

Now we apply substitution rule and substitute $S$ for $p$:

$S\rightarrow (\lnot S\rightarrow q)$

After rule of detachment (since $S$ is a theorem):

$\lnot S\rightarrow q$

After rule of detachment (since $\lnot S$ is also a theorem):

$q$

So we conclude that any sentence $q$ must be derivable. Now we notice that our axioms and transformation rules only allow us to produce tautologies, so only tautologies are derivable. So since every sentence $q$ is not derivable, we have a contradiction.

Have I understood the proof correctly? But I think there is a more obvious way of proving it:

We first observe that only tautologies are derivable by our system. Now, by the definition of negation operation, both $S$ and $\lnot S$ can't be tautologies. So at least one of them has to be non-derivable.

This proof sounds simple. I might be missing something. Anything wrong with this proof?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your source? Or a reference?

Comment: Besides, what is the definition of consistency?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco If two contradicting theorems can't be proved then the axioms are consistent.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco page 8 of http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/JAC/124/GodelsProof.pdf

Comment: The first proof looks to me a circular argument for the principle of explosion. (There are valid arguments for POE.) What has this to do with consistency?

Comment: @DanChristensen How is it circular?

Comment: The Principle of Explosion can be stated as follows: For any propositions $A$ and $B$, we have (1) $A \land \neg A \implies B$, or equivalently (2) $A \implies (\neg A \implies B)$. You set out to prove that for any propositions $S$ and $q$, we have $ S \land \neg S \implies q$ as in (1). You start by assuming that $S \land \neg S$ is true. Then, using (2), you infer that $q$ must also be true. You are using (2) to prove (1), but they are both equivalent definitions of POE. Thus the circularity.  This does seem to me to be a proof of the consistency of propositional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both arguments are correct and clearly your second argument is more concise and elegant, if you already know a bit of logic.

By the way, your [source](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/JAC/124/GodelsProof.pdf) is an excellent article to popularize logic $(*)$. 
I guess the main aim of that article is to write not the shortest proof of consistency but the "most informative" one for a reader that is not an expert. More precisely, in their proof of consistency of propositional logic, the authors introduce many interesting and relevant concepts, for instance:

1. if a deductive system is not consistent (i.e. if there *exists* a formula $S$ such that both $S$ and its negation $\lnot S$ are derivable) then *every* formula is derivable in such a system;
2. the deductive system introduced in the article (essentially, Hilbert calculus for propositional logic) is *sound*, i.e. it can derive only tautologies.

This is, I guess, the reason why the authors preferred to show a longer path to conclude that propositional logic is consistent.

---

$(*)$ It is a short version of Nagel and Newman's book "[Gödel's Proof](https://books.google.com/books/about/G%C3%B6del_s_Proof.html?id=FtclgZ1yYDEC)", which I highly recommend to read if you are interested in logic, its motivations and its most famous result, Gödel's theorems.

Comment: The pdf is a simplified version of the proof of Godel's theorems, which is fine for a beginner like me. I'm also interested in understanding the full rigorous proof. Does the long version of the book cover that? What logic concepts should I study to understand Godel's original proof as it is?

Comment: @RyderRude - Nagel and Newman's book has the same informal and introductory style as their article you cited. But it contains much more explanations, comments, examples. It's very interesting. A more rigorous approach is in Peter Smith's "[Introduction to Gödel’s Theorems](https://www.logicmatters.net/igt/)", but it requires some basic notions in first-order formal logic and is addressed to advanced undergraduated or postgraduated students. You can also ask for some references in a separate question, maybe other people can suggest other books.